# Softkey Position for Kit Kat

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat

On my old Tablet which was a Honeycomb on a Toshiba Thrive. The softkeys were on the left hand side when you were in landscape. Which Is convenient. When I use my Nexus 7 2013 I keep having to stretch my thumbs over to the middle to hit the home softkey.

My phone is rooted but I dont want to use cyanogenmod as when I used it it crashed several times in 1 hour yet I have used the stock rom for 100's hours with no crashes what so ever.

And advice on how to get the softkeys back to the left side?

PS: No floating softkey apps as that is a quick and dirty.

Comment: [ParanoidAndroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1800268) has this as an option. I'm with you in that I much prefer having the notification bar on the bottom-right and navbar on the bottom-left - that's one of the main reasons why I put PA on my N7 (Back when I had one).

Comment: @dotVezz Thanks for tip, incredible app, would be more incredible if I didn't need to go down the flash ROM route. Rather stick to stock ROM.